# Finding the right ideals of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ (matrices over a field $\mathbb{F}$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> I'm trying to figure out all the possible right ideals of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$.

I know that the two-sided ideals are only the trivial ones, and the proof uses the fact that we can operate on the rows and line of a matrix to make $E_{ij}$ - the matrix that has one in ij and zero in the rest of it.

Does anyone have any idea(l)?

Thanks.

Comment: Here are some previous posts on this question: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26726/what-are-the-left-and-right-ideals-of-matrix-ring-how-about-the-two-sided-ideal), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336957/right-ideal-in-a-matrix-ring), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311662/a-question-regarding-one-sided-right-and-left-ideals-their-calculation-for-matr). Do any of these answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for you response. I dont think so, because in my case I have the ring of matrices over a field. I think it might be related to the fact that multiplication from the right must produce a matrix with its columns spanning the ideal vector space.

Comment: Hm, okay. How about [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586280/any-left-ideal-of-m-n-mathbbf-is-principal)? (I realize it's about left ideals, but I think the answers can be modified for right ideals.)